# SSRS subscription with Oracle data source

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

We have an SSRS with Oracle as data source. Creating report Works, but creating subscriptions doesn't.

On the Data Source configuration page,i use Oracle internal user and enabled "Credentials stored securely on the report server". If i click Test Connectiong, it says the connectiong was succesful.

Creating a subscription gives the error "Subscriptions cannot be created because the credentials used to run the report are not stored, or if a linked report, the link is no longer valid."

Something i found out is that the reports i create have as data source :

Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Production and Windows Integrated Security as credentials.

Shouldn't Oracle be the data source and what can i do to correctly configure the subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

seems datasource credentials are your windows credentials, try changing it to your oracle database credentials. check below link for more information of connection strings. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/oracle-connection-type-ssrs

Comment: I am using Oracle internal user as datasource credentials, but the created reports have Windows Credentials used. Idk how is that posible, since i'm accesing data From Oracle to create reports.

Comment: you need oracle client tools installed, check if those are installed. more on creating datasource with oracle, check below link and follow the steps. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/834305/how-to-use-reporting-services-to-configure-and-to-access-an-oracle-dat